# Android studio 3.1 design editor not working and moreover it's showing gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-studio

For preview it's showing.
Preview is unavailable until a successful build 
And for gradle sync error it's showing

> Gradle sync failed :cause services. Gradle. Org

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project, then if you have resolved the dependencies before, you can turn on Offline Gradle Sync.

You can enable it by Preferences | Settings | Build, Execution, Development | Gradle -> Offline Work

Answer (score -1):

This happens mostly when your internet connection is not proper so just go to build->clean project and then try to sync again it should work

Comment: Is there's any way to sync it offline

Comment: no gradle sync requires internet so without internet it is not possible